# Evaluating a double integral in Matlab with Dirac Delta function

Tags: matlab, image-processing, integral, wolframalpha

For an image processing project I need to calculate the following Integral in Matlab.

[image: Integral]

delta is the dirac delta function.

But the Problem is when I calculate some samples the output is always 0. My matlab code is as follows:

```
fun = @(x,y) dirac(0 - (x * cosd(135) + y * sind(135)));
```

`q = integral2(fun, 0, 40, 0, 60)`

When i calculate the same integral on wolfram alpha it shows the right results.

```
integrate DiracDelta(0-(x * cos(135) + y * sin(135))) dx dy, x=0 to 40, y = 0 to 60
```

[WolframAlphaLink](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+DiracDelta(0-(x+*+cos(135)+%2B+y+*+sin(135)))+dx+dy,+x%3D0+to+40,+y+%3D+0+to+60)

Is there a Problem with the Cosine or the Sine function?

Comment: If the integrand contains Dirac's delta "function" you need to do the integral symbolically, not numerically

Comment: Okay and you got any advise for doing that in Matlab?

Comment: syms x;
cdf = dirac(0 - (x * cosd(135) + y * sind(135)));
int(int(cdf,x,0,40),0,60) 

if i do it like that the "symbolically" way, it works. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: The reason it doesn't work is that, when integrating numerically, you pick specific locations at which to evaluate the function. The Dirac delta is only non-zero at a single point, which you are highly unlikely to hit in numerical integration.